# I can't create an instance of a class on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, instance

I'm trying to create a instance of a class but I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: DM_TemplateLoader::$load
>
> Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 147
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\controllers\DM_FormValidator.php
>   Line: 13 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_sys\libraries\Form_validation.php
>   on line 147 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object
>
> Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 147
>
> Backtrace:

This is my code:

**DM_FormValidator.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class DM_FormValidator extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sender_host', 'Host (Sender)', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {           
            require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/DM_TemplateLoader.php';
            $template_loader = new DM_TemplateLoader();
        }
    }
}
```

**DM_TemplateLoader.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class DM_TemplateLoader extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {  

        // Loading the URL helper
        $this->load->helper('url');     

        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Data Migrator: Home';

            // Building the template
            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/' . $page);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }
        else {
             show_404();
        }   
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a Controller inside another controller. You shouldn't do that. As I can see, you want to call your own function instead of directly loading a view. You have multiple solutions to do that, here's one :

**Create a library**

In your application/libraries folder create Layout.php (or whatever you want)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Layout
{
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function load_template($view)
    {
        // Loading the URL helper
        $this->ci->load->helper('url');     

        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) 
        {
            $data['page_title'] = 'Data Migrator: Home';

            // Building the template
            $this->ci->load->view('template/header', $data);
            $this->ci->load->view('pages/' . $page);
            $this->ci->load->view('template/footer');
        }
        else {
            show_404();
        }   
    }

}
```

**Load your library**

After that, in your application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('layout', yourotherstuff);
```

**Use it**

Finally, in your controller DM_FormValidator instead of instantiating your class just call the library :

```
$view = "mypage";
$this->layout->load_template($data);
```

You can also override the base load->view() (system/core/Loader.php) with yours. Take a look at the documentation : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: I tried your code and I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataMigrator\ci_my_app\libraries\Layout.php on line 15

Comment: Well the part that is not working is the one I took from your first post. I supposed you had an existing url helper. If not, just remove the line. But that part is up to you. ;)

Comment: Oh I see. I figured out that I can't use  $this->load->view('template/header', $data); anymore but it works when I use it like that: $this->ci->load->view('template/header', $data); I didn't understand what $this->ci =& get_instance(); should mean but anyway thank you!! Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: You can't access directly to codeigniter in a lib. You can't do $this->stuff. To do that, you need to "instantiate codeigniter". That what $this->ci =& get_instance() is for. With that you can access to codeigniter with $this->ci->stuff. Please make sure to validate the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Ok thanks for this information. This helped me a lot. Sorry, I can't vote up your answer, since I need at least 15 reputations to do that. I will as soon as I have them.

Comment: You don't need to up vote, just click on the grey check mark ✔ . Glad it helped ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to here. I did now. Thanks again ;)